# Does tempDB disk perf matter if you have plenty of unused memory?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2012, tempdb

We have a SQL Server 2012 Enterprise setup with a large amount of RAM (256 GB), and at this time fairly small databases (about 17GB). Right now we are experiencing performance issues due to various coding issues which will hopefully be resolved by some code reviews and optimization.  At the same time there is a movement to try to improve the performance by getting faster disk for the `tempDB` LUNs, like using a FusionIO PCIe flash card.

My concern is that given that SQL Server still has plenty of RAM to take advantage of, that we won't see any real performance improvement from adding faster disk.  I figure that most of the `tempDB` operations would take place in RAM, or take place on disk but end up cached in RAM (either on the host, HBA, or SAN).

Does anyone know if SQL Server 2012 will still end up waiting for IO blocking on `tempDB` disk operations when it has plenty of RAM to use, or is the `tempDB` disk activity we are seeing just there to provide persistence or durability?

Comment: Is tempdb even being used under your workload?

Comment: @usr makes a good point - it seems like there should be some profiling done here to determine what the real bottleneck is. If the issues are primarily in the code, then are you chasing a ghost by looking to the database for performance issues? You need to figure out what is slowest on the database end before assuming it's a tempdb issue.

Comment: First There is no SQL Server 2012 R2. Second is your SQL Server 2012 updated to SP2 and then preferably SP2 CU1. If not first please do it. SQL Server has history of creating suboptimal plan if RAM is high(sometimes) you could take benefit of trace flag 4199. Please read https://support2.microsoft.com/kb/974006?wa=wsignin1.0. Having said that I suspect this to be issue I am not sure. Since you mentioned about performance

Comment: My advise is first please filter down what is the issue. Is it rouge queries running or slow disk or any such thing related to hardware and then focus on resolving it. You seemed to be lost here

Comment: Sorry, Shanky is right, I confused OS and SQL.  SQL is 2012 SP1.  As far as tempDB use, we do see a LOT of activity on the tempDB LUN, it is getting twice the IOPs as our logs LUN, and 3 times what we see on our data LUN.

Comment: There are some changes in SQL Server 2014 of relevance http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2014/04/09/sql-server-2014-tempdb-hidden-performance-gem.aspx

Answer (score 6):

Even if you have plenty of DRAM, `tempdb` may still be used.

This happens in a few situations:

**Snapshot isolation:** Using this feature can create a lot of tempdb activity.

**Hash and sort Spills**: When the optimiser creates a query plan, it will try to estimate the total amount of memory it needs to run the query. Before the query runs, the estimated memory is allocated. If it turns out (for example, due to bad statistics) that the allocated memory is too small, then SQL Server will spill operators like hash tables and sort buffers to `tempdb`, EVEN if there is enough memory after the query has started to satisfy the requirement.

Or course, if your queries are perfectly tuned and you run without snapshot isolation, you can avoid these effects. But in most situations, some amount of `tempdb` activity is to be expected, even on a large DRAM system.